# Oracle context index: doesn't work over dblink

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

There are two db's, table test_table on db1 with context index by field a. Query:

```
select *
  from test_table t
 where contains(t.a, 'str') > 0
```

It works fine on db1. But when I try execute same query over dblink from other database:

```
select *
  from test_table@db1 t
 where contains(t.a, 'str') > 0
```

I get this error:

ora-20000: Oracle Text Error:
 DRG-10599: column is not indexed

Comment: Have you considered creating a view of your query (with the predicate) in db1 and then query the view using the database link in db2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add dblink to function. 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/csql.htm#CCREF0104

> The CONTAINS operator also supports database links. You can identify a
>   remote table or materialized view by appending @dblink to the end of
>   its name. The dblink must be a complete or partial name for a database
>   link to the database containing the remote table or materialized view.
>   (Querying of remote views is not supported.)

```
select *
  from test_table@db1 t
 where contains(t.a, 'str')@db1 > 0.
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, the only clarification - the correct version looks like this:

select *
  from test_table@db1 t
 where contains@db1(t.a, 'str') > 0.